# CodeIgniter Image Upload (Insert blank into array)

Tags: php, image, codeigniter, file-upload

The form I'm working with contains info for five people. Optionally, the user can upload a photo for each of the five people. I'm attempting to insert a default image into the resulting array $files where an image is not uploaded. Help would be greatly appreciated.

```
function multiple_upload($upload_dir = APPPATH, $config = array())
{
    $CI =& get_instance();
    $files = array();

    if(empty($config))
    {
        $config['upload_path']   = realpath($upload_dir . '/uploads');
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|jpeg|jpe|png';
        $config['max_size']      = '2048';
    }

    $CI->load->library('upload', $config);

    $errors = FALSE;
    $this->load->library('image_lib');  // moved outside loop so it'll work
    foreach($_FILES as $key => $value)
    {
        if( ! empty($value['name']))
        {
            if( ! $CI->upload->do_upload($key))
            {
                $data['upload_message'] = $CI->upload->display_errors(ERR_OPEN, ERR_CLOSE); // ERR_OPEN and ERR_CLOSE are error delimiters defined in a config file
                $CI->load->vars($data);

                $errors = TRUE;
            }
            else
            {

                // resize the saved image
                $path = $CI->upload->data('full_path');
                //echo $path['full_path'] . "<Br/>";
                $config = array(
                    'source_image' => $path['full_path'],
                    'new_image' => $upload_dir . 'uploads/thumbs',
                    'maintain_ration' => true,
                    'width' => 150,
                    'height' => 150
                );

                $this->image_lib->initialize($config);
                $this->image_lib->resize();
                // Build a file array from all uploaded files
                $files[] = $CI->upload->data();


            }
        }
    }

    // There was errors, we have to delete the uploaded files
    if($errors)
    {
        foreach($files as $key => $file)
        {
            @unlink($file['full_path']);
        }
    }
    elseif(empty($files) AND empty($data['upload_message']))
    {
        $CI->lang->load('upload');
        $data['upload_message'] = ERR_OPEN.$CI->lang->line('upload_no_file_selected').ERR_CLOSE;
        $CI->load->vars($data);
    }
    else
    {

        return $files;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be easier to do your check after you validate the uploaded files.

For example:  Initialize an array with five empty elements, one for each picture, then for each file that's uploaded, set its filename to the appropriate array element.  When you're done, just run through and for any empty elements, just tack in the file (or file path) to your default image.

This way, you keep your file uploading and validation as vanilla as possible, and deal with the business logic of your page separately.